# redis in Dash: Maximum recursion level reached

Tags: python, redis, plotly-dash

I am building a Dash application in Python 3.7. Specifically, I want to use redis for pre-computing an entire figure, but get an error "Maximum recursion level reached."

I follow "Example 4", "Part 6, Sharing Data Between Callbacks" of the official Dash Tutorial (https://dash.plot.ly/sharing-data-between-callbacks). However, in contrast to that example, I want to pre-compute not some data, but the entire figure. That is because I receive large datasets -- meteorological data over time -- that load very slowly because of their size, and hence I thought of pre-computing the figure beforehand. Anyway, I can built the app without the precompute part, but trying to modify it throws that error message from deep inside the Dash engine.

```py
import os, sys, uuid
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash
import plotly
from flask_caching import Cache
import pandas
import numpy

sys.setrecursionlimit(500000)   # doesn't help!

N = 50000   # big number

# start Dash application
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
cache = Cache(app.server, config={
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis',
    'CACHE_DIR': 'cache-directory',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379'),
    'CACHE_THRESHOLD': 10
})

def get_dataframe(session_id):
    @cache.memoize()
    def query_and_serialize_data(session_id):
        prep = pandas.DataFrame({
            'data': [plotly.graph_objs.Scattergl(
                x=[index for index in range(0, N)],   # time index
                y=numpy.random.rand(N),               # data points
                mode='lines+markers'
            )]
        })
        return prep.to_json()
    return pandas.read_json(query_and_serialize_data(session_id))

def serve_layout():
    session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return html.Div([
        # hidden
        html.Div(session_id, id='session-id', style={'display': 'none'}),
        # graph
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='graph')])
    ])

app.layout = serve_layout

# update graph
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('session-id', 'children')])
def update_graph_figure(session_id):
    #data = [plotly.graph_objs.Scattergl(
    #    x=[index for index in range(0, N)],   # time index
    #    y=numpy.random.rand(N),               # data points
    #    mode='lines+markers'
    #)]                                        # valid data to 'graph'
    prep = get_dataframe(session_id)
    return {'data': prep['data']}

# main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The error message follows a long call list:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>   ...
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 161, in _write
>       iso_dates, default_handler)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\json.py", line 115, in _write
>       default_handler=default_handler
>   OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached

How should I correct the code? And if the very idea does not work, how can I speed up the load time in some other way?

Comment: Python recursive functions use a lot of memory because of this they aren't suitable for recursion for a very high N. can you transform this code that currently uses recursion to an iterative one ?

Comment: @Eufrasia. The recursion is deep inside the Dash / plotly engine, not my code! However, why does the same code snippet work when placed inside update_graph_figure -- just uncomment those 5 lines -- and re-calculated with each call to that dcc.Graph with id='graph', but fails when calculated once in a pd.DataFrame and placed in a redis cache?